# React setState variable stops re-rendering components using it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, react-dom

## Problem

1. Function parseLocalStorage returns a object
2. White using setStorage(parseLocalStorage()) at useState:-

> - Storage does'nt get modified
> - setStorage used in other functions (like <Element setStorage={setStorage} / > ) stops working

3. I have searched all other occurrences of setStorage but they aren't the cause as they occur onEvents(like when the message is sent, a new chat etc.)

### Tldr : useState preventing render of component [Video](https://jumpshare.com/b/7F5QXc5Z6zTLtHlzgt0q)

## Code

### Highly simplified as Orginal is large

```js
const Main = () =>{ 
const [hasParsed , setHasParsed] = useState(false);
const [storage, setStorage] = useState({ 
    rootId: "1",                           
    items: {
      "1": {
        id: "1",
        children: ["1-1"],
        hasChildren: true,
        isExpanded: true,
        isChildrenLoading: false,
        data: {
          title: "root"
        }
      },
      "1-1" : {
        id: "1-1",
        children: ["1-1-1"],
        hasChildren: true,
        isExpanded: false,
        isChildrenLoading: false,
        data: {
          title: "folder-new Folder"
        }
      },
      "1-1-1" : {
        id: "1-1-1",
        children: [],
        hasChildren: false,
        isExpanded: false,
        isChildrenLoading: false,
        data: {
          title: "chat-New Chat",
          messages : []
        }
      }
    }
  });

 const parseLocalStorage = () =>{
         // parses localStorage perfectly and returns it
       return parsedLocalStorage;
} 

useEffect(() =>{
  if(!hasParsed)
  {
      setStorage(parseLocalStorage());
     setHasParsed(false);
    // This part causes issues 
    // Storage does'nt get modified
    //  - setStorage used in other functions 
    // (like <Element setStorage={setStorage} / >  ) stops   working

  }
}

render() {
 return(
    <div>
       // This element probably did'nt cause the issue as it only modifies the storage at button click.
        <Element storage={storage} setStorage={setStorage} />
    </div>
   )
}

}

export default Main;
```

## Situation:

- I am making a ChatGPT client using React.
- I have a feature where the data of of the chat messages is copied to the localStorage when the a message is sent or a chat or folder is created.
- The localStorage has to be read and copied to the storage variable when the app starts.
- I have a function called parseLocalStorage which does this successfully but the setStorage does'nt seem to work...
- I used the @atlaskit/tree package to generate the folder structure

### I tried

- Using UseEffect with dependancies
- Understanding that set< Variable > in useState only updates on next cycle and adjusting my code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.